# Overflow Hidden for div inside a div

Tags: css, html, overflow, hidden

I have an outer div and inside it, I have an image and another div. Now, the outer div has a certain width and height and has an `overflow: hidden;` Now my image works fine, meaning that even though it's bigger than the div it won't overflow.

The problem i am having is with the other div that's inside the outer div. This inner div is above the image that i have. But it still wouldn't show. But after I positioned it to absolute. It worked properly.

After that I positioned outside the barriers of the outer div. Now, since I made the overflow of the outer div hidden, it shouldn't show right? Yet, the inner div shows. So here is what I would like solved.

- Why wasn't the inner div showing initially and why did i have to give the div the property of `position:absolute;`?
- Why are is my inner div still showing outside the boundaries of my outer div even though my outer div has the property of `overflow` to `hidden`.
- How do I hide my inner div when its not inside the outer div. Now, note that I do not want the inner div to actually hide. I just want it not seen unless it's in my outer div.

Here is my source code for reference:

- The css property of the outer div:

  ```
  .banner {
      width: 250px;
      height: 500px;
      overflow: hidden;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  ```
- The css property of the inner div:

  ```
  div.info {
       position: absolute;
       width: 250px;
       height: 500px;
       top: 0px;
       opacity: 0.70;
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
  }
  ```

Here is a link to a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jMX3n/2/

Comment: have you got a fiddle replicating your problem?

Comment: give fiddle, that's better.

Comment: @ADeveloper, so we have to create an example page to see how your code is working on our own, without even seeing what your html is? How nice of you to ask for help and not offer us help in helping you.

Comment: @ADeveloper Well you should give a fiddle though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net it's not really complicated you'll see. No need to be registered.

Comment: @ADeveloper: You don'y *have* to create a fiddle, but you should include all code to replicate the issue. It's just usually easier for everyone if a fiddle is provided along with the question for problems like this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jMX3n/2/ here is the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution. I deleted the outer div with the id of `#banner`. And then to the `.banner` class, I added `position: relative` and then shifted the div a little. Apparently I had multiple div's similar to the inner div I was describing. In my `.banner` class I added the property `float:left;`. The overflow worked properly. Here is the new code:

**The div class:**

```
.banner {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**The inner div:**

```
div.info {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 0px;
    left: -250px;
    opacity: 0.70;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the fiddle, the middle div (.banner) isn't positioned, so the absolute positioning of the inner div (.info) is with respect to the outermost div (#banner), which does have position, but does not have `overflow:hidden`.

Therefore, in order to hide the overflow, add `overflow:hidden` to the outermost div as well.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
http://jsfiddle.net/Augustus06111993/Rkgfy/

Since no Fiddle, I am taking a shot in the dark.. 
Since you used absolute position it will override your overflow method because

> This tells the browser that whatever is going to be positioned should
>   be removed from the normal flow of the document and will be placed in
>   an exact location on the page. It is also taken out of the normal flow
>   of the document - it won't affect how the elements before it or after
>   it in the HTML are positioned on the Web page

Your outer div and inner div have same dimensions.. Try changing the css of inner div like this and you can see your image and div seperately

```
.info {
     width: 50%;
     height: 50%;
     float:left;
     opacity: 0.70;
}

.image {
     width:50%;
     height:50%;
}

.outer {
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: no, its not working. I've given the link to the fiddle, so you can see that